# Regex: binary string whose length is a multiple of 3?

Tags: regex

How do I write a regular expression for binary strings such that it's length is a multiple of 3 and this must include the empty string. 
So for example
010 is true
0101 is false.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wrap your regex inside the `^` `$` so that it performs matching over the whole string.

```
^([01]{3})*$
```

Comment: Nice and compact, I have been noticing and like your regex style. Upvoting. :)

Answer (score 4):

The following should work:

```
^(?:[01]{3})*$
```

Edit: non-capture group for optimization.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I would suggest:

```
^(?:[01]{3})*$
```

It matches the pattern you need, but does not capture the group which is taken into the brackets.

Explanation:

```
^ // matches beginning of the string
    (?: // opens a non-capturing group
        [01] // a symbol class, which could only contain 0's or 1's
        {3} // repeat exactly three times
    ) // closes the previously opened group
    * // repeat [0, infinity] times
$ // matches the end of the string
```